# using update ca certificate in docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am containerizing a dotnet core application. In the dockerfile we are copying a .p7b file using the below command. Everything works fine, but I do not truly understand what is the purpose of adding this certificate

```
COPY ["src/pathtocert/certnew.p7b", "."]
RUN openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certnew.p7b -out hostname.crt
RUN cp hostname.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

Why do we need the above update-ca-certificates in docker file ?
Is it required during build time or when the image is run in a Kubernetes container environment

Viewing the .p7b file shows issuing CA and root CA each having a different longer expiry more than 30 years.

Will the running containers fail when it reaches expiry ?

Comment: update-ca-certificates is a program that updates the directory /etc/ssl/certs to hold SSL certificates and generates ca-certificates.crt, a concatenated single-file list of certificates. - taken from "man update-ca-certificates"

Answer (score 1):

> *Why do we need the above update-ca-certificates in docker file ? Is it required during build time or when the image is run in a Kubernetes
> container environment*

It will be needed by your container in helping decide if a certificate should be trusted. Most likely software you are running will trust certs issued by this CA. The command will add this CA to the trusted list of CAs

> *Viewing the .p7b file shows issuing CA and root CA each having a different longer expiry more than 30 years.*

That's not unusal

> *Will the running containers fail when it reaches expiry ?*

No the containers won't fail. The software using the trust store might however.